# JSP custom tag for displaying a large event type calendar

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jodatime

This is probably a simple question, but what is everyone using to display a simple event calendar in jsp. I was looking for an existing taglib but didn't really find anything other than calendarTag.

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0, JodaTime. and basically just want a large calendar on a jsp where I can include links to another pager  based on some logic. Not really anything fancy.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Are you open to JSF and/or jQuery? There are a lot of tags (components) and/or plugins for this available. Spring MVC is not really UI component oriented MVC, it's more a HTTP request/action oriented MVC.

Comment: I think jquery is the way to go also.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the calendar in the controller, for example like this:

```
@Controller
public class CalendarController{

    private static final int START_OF_WEEK = DateTimeConstants.MONDAY;

    @RequestMapping("drawCalendar")
    public ModelAndView drawCalendar(@RequestParam("month") final int month,
        @RequestParam("year") final int year){
        final LocalDate monthStart = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
        boolean endReached = false;
        LocalDate today = null;
        final List<List<LocalDate>> weeks1 = new ArrayList<List<LocalDate>>();
        while(!endReached){
            final List<LocalDate> thisWeek = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
            for(int weekOffset = 0; weekOffset < 7; weekOffset++){
                if(today == null){
                    if(!endReached
                        && weekOffset == monthStart.getDayOfWeek()
                            - START_OF_WEEK){
                        today = monthStart;
                    }
                } else{
                    today = today.plusDays(1);
                    if(today.getMonthOfYear() != month){
                        today = null;
                        endReached = true;
                    }
                }
                thisWeek.add(today);
            }
            weeks1.add(thisWeek);
        }
        final List<List<LocalDate>> weeks = weeks1;

        final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("calendar", weeks);
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("calendar", model);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and in the JSP I would iterate over the weeks:

```
<c:forEach items="${calendar}" var="week">
    <tr>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thu</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${week}" var="date">
            <td><c:out value="${date==null ? '' : date.dayOfWeek}"</td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

(of course I haven't written any JSP code in about 3 years, so sorry if something is wrong)